# How to automatically convert UNIX Epoch Timestamp to Timestamp Column in Snowflake during ingestion

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unix-timestamp

I'm doing some CDC from MySQL to Snowflake using Debezium and i'm running into an issue with UNIX Timestamps.  Most of my timestamp columns are stored as UNIX Timestamps and when I'm loading the data into Snowflake I get an `Invalid Date` Error for these values when the Snowflake column is set to `TIMESTAMP`.  When the Snowflake Column is set to `VARCHAR` or `NUMBER`  then the values are recongized as `1687717314`, but this still isn't in a `TIMESTAMP` format that you'd actually want or can do any date manipulation with.

Obviously Snowflake has the `TO_TIMESTAMP()` function which works, but I have 50+ tables with over 150+ Timestamp Columns and this requires a pretty serious amount of manual effort to convert those columns to `TIMESTAMP` columns *after* ingestion.  Is there any way I can get Snowflake to convert these UNIX Timestamps directly to `TIMESTAMP` values during ingestion?

In the event that Snowflake doesn't have this capability, I'm in the process of converting the UNIX Timestamps to normal timestamps like `2023-06-23T14:33:44Z` on Debezium + Kafka's end, but this requires a transformation in the Debezium Connector for every single UNIX Timestamp column so it's pretty much equally as inconvenient at scale.

Here's an example: the `CREATED` column is a `VARCHAR` and the `MODIFIED` column is a `TIMESTAMP` column.  They both have the same values in the .json file (`"created":1687462844000, "modified":1687462844000`).

[image]

The File Format I'm using is the default JSON one, and here's the COPY INTO Statement:

```
copy into staging.cdc_source.orders
from @SNOWFLAKE_SINK_STG/topics/staging.orders/
file_format = 'json_format'
match_by_column_name = 'CASE_INSENSITIVE';
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please show an example of failed query from Snowflake QUERY_HISTORY?

Comment: How are you ingesting the data into Snowflake? Are you using a Snowflake process, such as a COPY INTO statement, or is an external tool writing the data using INSERT/UPDATE statements?

Comment: I'm using Snowpipe with auto ingest enabled and a json file format, but i get the same results if i manually run a copy into statement on my end.  The timestamp columns look like this `"created":1687288185000`.  i guess i expected to find some timestamp parameters on the file format, or some way to run `TO_TIMESTAMP()` on ingestion but i dont think that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

While I was solving a similar "problem", the simplest solution for me was to define the TARGET table with columns that have a defined DEFAULT value that performs that transformation.

This is how the TARGET is defined:

```
CREATE TABLE EPOCH_TEST (
    CREATED NUMBER(38,0),
    CREATED_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) DEFAULT (TO_TIMESTAMP(CREATED/1000)),
    MODIFIED NUMBER(38,0),
    MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) DEFAULT (TO_TIMESTAMP(MODIFIED/1000))
);
```

Example of an insert:

```
  insert into EPOCH_TEST (CREATED,MODIFIED)
  values(1687462844000,1687462844000);
```

The result:

```
CREATED             1687462844000
CREATED_TIMESTAMP   2023-06-22 19:40:44.000
MODIFIED            1687462844000
MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP  2023-06-22 19:40:44.000
```